# Discrete Logarithm problems

Tags: group-theory, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I'm trying to teach myself Cryptography and came across some old exam questions which include questions about the discrete logarithm, I'm just wondering if it's as straight forward as I'm thinking it is:

$ p=37, \space g=3 $

**(a)** Explain how to solve $ 27= g^x\space mod \space p $ for x without using brute force.

**(b)** Make a table of $ g^n\space mod \space p \space for \space n =1...18.$

**(c)** Is g a generator for $ Z^×_{37}? $ Say why.

**(d)** Using the table above, $ 4= g^y \space mod \space p \space for \space y $ by brute force.

If anyone can shed a bit of light on these it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward.  (b), (c) and (d)  are just computations. (a) is almost a trick.

Comment: Hi thank you for responding! How do I find if g is a generator?

Comment: Since you will have made a table in (b), look at the value computed for $g^{18}$. If $g^{18}\equiv1$, then $g$ is not a generator. Otherwise $g$ is a generator. We check the power $18$ because $\phi(p-1)=18$.

Comment: @EthanHunt I'd rather say "If you get to $g^{18}$ and haven't gotten $1$ then you can't get to $1$ until $36$ so $g$ is a generator."

Comment: @EthanBolker That is a good point; if $g^{n}\equiv1$ for any value of $n<18$, $g$ is not a generator as well.

Answer (score 1):

**(a)** Explain how to solve $ 27= g^x\space mod \space p $ for x without using brute force.

In the given case You can apply logarithm $x = \log_327=3$

For more complicated cases you cann use [Baby-step Giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) for example
:

$$3^x \equiv 27 (\text{ mod } 37)$$
$\varphi(37) = 36$
$m = \lceil \sqrt{36} \rceil = 6$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
j& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
 3^j & 1 & 3& 9 & \color{#f00}{27} & 7 & 21 
\end{array}$

$3^{-6}= 3^{36 -6 } = 3^{30} \text{ mod }37 = 10$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
i & 0 \\
\hline
 27\cdot 10^i & \color{#f00}{27}
\end{array}$

Also... $$x = i\cdot m + j = 0\cdot 6 + 3 = 3 $$
$$3^{3} \equiv 27 (\text{ mod } 37)$$

**(b)** Make a table of $ g^n\space mod \space p \space for \space n =1...18.$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
j& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
\hline
 3^j & 1 & 3& 9 & 27 & 7 & 21 & 26 & 4 & 12 &36 & 34 & 29 & 10 & 30 & 16 & 11 & 33 & 25 & 1
\end{array}$

**(c)** Is g a generator for $ Z^×_{37}? $ Say why. 
(shown the Comment from Ethan Bolker).

**(d)** Using the table above, $ 4= g^y \space mod \space p \space for \space y $ by brute force.

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
j& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
 3^j & 1 & \color{#f00}{3}& 9 & 27 & 7 & 21 
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
i & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
 4\cdot 10^i & 4 & \color{#f00}{3}
\end{array}$

Also... $$x = i\cdot m + j = 1\cdot 6 + 1 = 7 $$
$$3^{7} \equiv 4 (\text{ mod } 37)$$

I hope I was of help

Comment: Your answers to (c) and (d) are wrong. Your "answer" to (a) is weird. Please delete before you accumulate lots of downvotes.

Comment: The response to point C
$GCD (g, p) = 1 \implies GCD (g^x, p) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, so is is g a generator  for $\mathbb{Z}^x_{37}$.

For points A and B I applied the algorithm Baby-step giant-step. What is wrong here?

Comment: $3$ is not a generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{37}^*$ because $g^{18}$ is the identity (according to your correct table in (b)) so you can generate only half the elements of the multiplicative group. It is a generator of the cyclic group  $\mathbb{Z}_{37}$ under addition. Your answer to (d) is correct, but I don't know why you say all that stuff before noting that it's in the table.

Comment: I just wanted to give two examples, how the algorithm works ..

Point C, thanks for the correction, you're right.